# How to get data with python in certain rows and columns

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have data, example :

```
2017/06/07 10:42:35,THREAT,url,192.168.1.100,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423523,,web-browsing,80,tcp,block-url
2017/06/07 10:43:35,THREAT,url,192.168.1.101,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423047,,web-browsing,80,tcp,allow
2017/06/07 10:43:36,THREAT,end,192.168.1.100,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423047,,web-browsing,80,tcp,block-url
2017/06/07 10:44:09,TRAFFIC,end,192.168.1.101,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423111,,web-browsing,80,tcp,allow
2017/06/07 10:44:09,TRAFFIC,end,192.168.1.103,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423111,,web-browsing,80,tcp,block-url
```

How to parse that only get data columns 4,5,7, and 12 in all rows?

This is my code :

```
import csv

file=open('filename.log', 'r')
f=open('fileoutput', 'w')
lines = file.readlines()

        for line in lines:
        result.append(line.split(' ')[4,5,7,12])
        f.write (line)

f.close()
file.close()
```

Comment: You meant to write `result`, not `line`, right? And your input doesn't match your code-- it cannot be split on `' '`. And ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path, but your syntax is off. Here's an example using `csv` module:

```
import csv
log = open('filename.log')
# newline='\n' to prevent csv.writer to include additional newline when writing to file
log_write = open('fileoutput', 'w', newline='\n')
csv_log = csv.reader(log, delimiter=',')
csv_writer = csv.writer(log_write, delimiter=',')

for line in csv_log:
    csv_writer.writerow([line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3]]) # output first 4 columns

log.close()
log_write.close()
```

Comment: You forgot to add field separators and newlines. (Also, that's what the `csv` module is for)

Comment: @alexis thanks, now i want to parse the data to display the row whose second column is THREAT and the fourth column is ip 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.101. how to code to run it?

Comment: @yusuf, seriously? Learn how this site works. And ask questions that'll help you learn how to program, don't just slice your project into pieces and try to delegate it here.

Comment: @alexis I've tried and I've also asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380386/how-to-get-value-in-colums-with-python

Comment: I checked your question. I'm sorry to say it but you can't expect a very friendly reception on this site with this kind of question. You need to help yourself, learn the basics so you can ask coherent questions. It's ok not to know things and to try to learn, but if there are multiple things wrong with your code that are not even what you're asking about, there's no good way to help you.

Answer (score 3):

The right way with `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` objects:

```
import csv

with open('filename.log', 'r') as fr, open('filoutput.csv', 'w', newline='') as fw:
    reader = csv.reader(fr)
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    for l in reader:
        writer.writerow(v for k,v in enumerate(l, 1) if k in (4,5,7,12))
```

---

`filoutput.csv` contents:

```
192.168.1.100,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423523,block-url
192.168.1.101,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423047,allow
192.168.1.100,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423047,block-url
192.168.1.101,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423111,allow
192.168.1.103,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423111,block-url
```

Comment: I've tried, but can not. when i run .py appear comment  this TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @baharudinyusuf, It seems that you are on Python 2.7, you should have mentioned that in your question

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
line.split(' ')[4,5,7,12]
```

You want this:

```
fields = line.split(' ')
fields[4], fields[5], fields[7], fields[12]
```

Comment: I've tried, but can not. this my code
import csv

file=open('file.log', 'r')
f=open('file', 'w')
lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
        fields = line.split(' ')
        fields[4], fields[5]
        f.write (line)

f.close()
file.close()

Comment: Cannot ah?  Where got cannot?

Comment: File "parsingcolom.py", line 7
    for line in lines:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: So you've entered code in the wrong format (unexpected indent).  But then you post the code in a comment where we cannot see your indentation.  We won't be able to help you like this.

Answer (score 1):

a solution using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.log', sep=',', header=None, index_col=False)
df[[3, 4, 6, 11]].to_csv('fileoutput.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Note the use of `[3, 4, 6, 11]` instead of `[4, 5, 7, 12]` to account for 0-indexing in the dataframe's columns.

Content of `fileoutput.csv`:

```
192.168.1.100,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423523,block-url
192.168.1.101,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423047,allow
192.168.1.100,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423047,block-url
192.168.1.101,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423111,allow
192.168.1.103,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423111,block-url
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the list compressions, you could have something like this without necessarily using csv module

```
file=open('filename.log','r') 
f=open('fileoutput', 'w')
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    f.write(','.join(line.split(',')[i] for i in [3,4,6,11]))

f.close()
file.close()
```

Notice the indices are 3,4,6,11 for our zero index based list

output

```
cat fileoutput 
192.168.1.100,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423523,block-url
192.168.1.101,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423047,allow
192.168.1.100,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423047,block-url
192.168.1.101,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423111,allow
192.168.1.103,52.25.xxx.xxx,13423111,block-url
```