# How to filter lines by column in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to filter some lines of a `.csv` file:

```
2017/06/07 10:42:35,THREAT,url,192.168.1.100,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423523,,web-browsing,80,tcp,block-url
2017/06/07 10:43:35,THREAT,url,192.168.1.101,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423047,,web-browsing,80,tcp,allow
2017/06/07 10:43:36,THREAT,end,192.168.1.102,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423047,,web-browsing,80,tcp,block-url
2017/06/07 10:44:09,TRAFFIC,end,192.168.1.101,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423111,,web-browsing,80,tcp,allow
2017/06/07 10:44:09,TRAFFIC,end,192.168.1.103,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423111,,web-browsing,80,tcp,block-url
```

I want to filter lines containing the string "THREAT" in the second column AND lines containing the ips 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.101 in the fourth column.

This is my implementation so far:

```
import csv

file= open(file.log, 'r')
f= open(column, 'w')
lines = file.readlines() 
for line in lines:
        input = raw_input()
        col = line.split(',') 
        if line.find(col[1])=="THREAT":
                f.write (line)
        if line.find(col[3]==192.168.1.100 && 192.168.101:
                f.write (line)
        else:
                pass

f.close()
file.close()
```

What is wrong with the code? This is the output I'm expecting to get:

```
2017/06/07 10:42:35,THREAT,url,192.168.1.100,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423523,,web-browsing,80,tcp,block-url
2017/06/07 10:43:35,THREAT,url,192.168.1.101,52.25.xxx.xxx,Rule-VWIRE-03,13423047,,web-browsing,80,tcp,allow
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Mureinik code that I run on is wrong, I do not know where to go wrong. I want to display data like the example below but can not.thank you

Comment: Do you know, that python do lists indexing from zero? `THREAT` is not in`col[2]`, it's in `col[1]`

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov I've changed it, but still can not

Comment: What on earth is `input = raw_input()` doing in your loop?

Comment: Another thing that's wrong is that IP addresses are not a python datatype. And that's not even the only syntax error on that line. You really need to learn some Python before you can get help with this kind of task here.

Answer (score 0):

You use `str.find` method, which returns index if found and -1 otherwise. In your case - if, for example, `THREAT` in line - it will return some non-zero number, but then you compare that number with string, which is obviously returns `False`.
Also, you can union those `if` statements.

So, taking into account the above - your `if` statements should be:

```
if col[1] == "THREAT" or col[3] in ["192.168.1.100", "192.168.1.101"]:
    f.write(line)
```

In addition - i don't understand, why you use `raw_input` on each iteration and never use again that value?

I suggest you use this little optimized code:

```
import csv  # not used in provide snippet, could be deleted

file_log = open("file.log", 'r')  # better to use absoulete path 
filtered_log = open("column", 'w')  # same as previous
for line in file:  # no need to read entire file, just iterate over it line by line directly
    col = line.split(',')
    if col and (col[1] == "THREAT" or col[3] in ["192.168.1.100", "192.168.1. 101"]):
        filtered_log.write(line)

file_log.close()
filtered_log.close()
```

Comment: I've tried your code pack, but when I run the codenya is an error.
The file "spesificColom.py", line 9, in <module>
     if col [1] == "THREAT" or col [3] in ["192.168.1.100", "192.168.1.101"]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Fixed with additional check

Comment: i've tried yout code has been changed sir, but still an error. i use pyhton2.7
 File "spesificColom.py", line 7, in <module>
    if col and (col[1] == "THREAT" or col[3] in ["192.168.1.100", "192.168.1. 101"]):
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Python's csv module provides a reader object which can be used to iterate over a `.csv` file lines.

In each line, you can extract column by it's index and apply some comparation logic before printing the line.

This implementation will filter the file as needed:

```
import csv

ip_list = ['192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101']
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in reader:
        if (line[1]=="THREAT") and (line[3] in ip_list):
            print(','.join(line))
```

As you can see, this implementation stores the ips in a list for comparing them using the python's `in` operator.